# How do you edit or simply add color to downloaded vector Icons?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, icon

I would like to know how to edit vector icons (that I downloaded from set) in photoshop.

I know this is probably a stupid question but i have been following a tutorial which involved downloading a vector icon set, then copying and pasting one of these icons (a mobile phone) into PS doc, which I have done. The next step is to fill the screen of the mobile vector with color.

I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Since they're vectors, this'll be much easier in a vector design application like Illustrator or [one of its alternatives](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80/alternative-to-adobe-illustrator) than in Photoshop

Comment: The tutorial said just to copy and paste the vector icon into photoshop and then fill the "screen" (inner part of icon... I will try to do this in Illustrator first then copy over.... ? Does this mean that the tutorial was wrong to suggest this method?

Comment: No idea if it's right or wrong but any work with vectors is easier in applications designed for working with vectors (it would also help if you edit a link to the tutorial into the question)

Answer (score -1):

Now, yes this would be far easier to do in Illustrator, or another vector program, so I am going to assume you either don't have these programs or just really want to learn how to do it in Photoshop.

Please see the screenshots below:

[image: YourPhone]

See the red circles, this is where you select Color Overlay

[image: next_color overlay]

Select your color

[image: select color]

Comment: The tutorial in question was http://www.sitepoint.com/design-flat-website-mockup-photoshop/   See: Step 7 Tablet. Thanks for help

Comment: Ok, so you want to just FILL one part of the tablet, not color the entire thing. Easy: select the inside (you can either do this with the magic wand or draw in the area with the lasso tool or the pen tool), next go to Edit > Fill and choose Contents Use: Color (from the dropdown) and add in the color you want to use.