# Business card texture and cutouts

Tags: print-design, texture, business, style

I am fairly new to the print media parts.

I have a client that requested a business card design. However they want their business card to have a certain texture and some parts need to be cut out. What do I need to do as a designer to ensure that I make it happen, or is it up to the printing company they decide to use?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do it is:

- use Adobe Illustrator or [equivalent software](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80) that can generate a vector format PDF output
- design the card as per client requirements
- add a separate layer with the shape of the areas that need to be cut out for print (yes, you need to do this, not the printer). these are called 'dielines' and are discussed here: [How should I set up dielines so that they are not printed?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28253). In short: draw the shape of the cut and use a spot color stroke on it, set that to overprint and move it on top of the artwork layer.
- discuss paper texture options with both client (what they want) and print provider (vs. what is available and at what cost)
- export to PDF and send to printer, including the dieline

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try it out and see what I can do.