# Photoshop or Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, vector

Can somebody tell me in which program this cartoon avatar was made?

[image]?

[cartoon avatar from avatoon.net](https://avatoon.net)

Comment: This could've been done in _any_ graphic editor: raster, vector, 3d. More convenient however would be making something similar in a vector editor.

Comment: This is like seeing a manuscript and then asking what computer it was typed on... there's no certain way to tell by looking at the final result in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be made in Photoshop, but much easier, and most likely, done in Illustrator or other similar vector-editing apps: [Alternative to Adobe Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/80/alternative-to-adobe-illustrator)

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me to be a vector illustration.

Comment: This doesn't answer "which program".